# SOT convergence of normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $T_n$ be a sequence of bounded normal operators on a Hilbert space which converges to a normal operator $T$ in the strong operator topology. Show that $T_n^*$ also converges to $T^*$ in SOT.

I have tried to telescope the terms but it leads to nowhere.

Comment: I think one has $\|T_n^\ast x - T^\ast x\|=\|T_n x - T x\|$. This would then easily imply the result.

Comment: @PhoemueX This formula was my first idea too, but it seems that for a proof $T_n T^\ast =T^\ast T_n$  is needed. I dont't see this.

Comment: See also here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309734/normal-operator-iff-norm-on-v-equivalent-to-that-of-adjoint

Comment: @PhoemueX I agree that $\|Tx\|= \|T^\ast x\|$ for a normal operator $T$, but the sum (or difference) of normal operators is not normal, in general, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368757/is-the-sum-of-two-normal-operators-normal

Comment: @Gerd: Oh, right, damn. I knew this at some point :) Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\|T_n^\ast x-T^\ast x\|^2 = \langle T_n^\ast x,T_n^\ast x \rangle 
-\langle T_n^\ast x,T^\ast x \rangle -\langle T^\ast x,T_n^\ast x \rangle +\langle T^\ast x,T^\ast x \rangle 
$$
$$
=\langle T_n x,T_n x \rangle -\langle  x,T_nT^\ast x \rangle -\langle T_nT^\ast x,x \rangle +\langle T x,T x \rangle 
$$
$$
\to \langle T x,T x \rangle -\langle  x,TT^\ast x \rangle -\langle TT^\ast x,x \rangle +\langle T x,T x \rangle 
$$
$$
=\langle T x,T x \rangle -\langle  x,T^\ast T x \rangle -\langle T^\ast T x,x \rangle +\langle T x,T x \rangle
$$
$$
=\langle T x,T x \rangle -\langle  Tx,T x \rangle -\langle  T x,Tx \rangle +\langle T x,T x \rangle =0.
$$