# positive definiteness of $\left[\begin{array}{cc}B & C^\top \\ C & B\end{array}\right]$

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A=B+jC$ is a positive semi-definite (psd) matrix in $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, where $B$ and $C$ are its real and imaginary parts.  Is the real matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}B & C^\top \\ C & B\end{array}\right]$ positive semidefinite?

Comment: Without thinking too much, the logic should presumably be: Let $v=\binom{x}{y}$ with $x,y$ as real vectors. If $v$ violates the positive-definiteness of the block matrix, then the complex vector $z=x+jy$ should do the same for $A$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Indeed.  Thanks a lot for the pointer.

Comment: If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then $C=0$ (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267300/positive-definite-matrix-must-be-hermitian). This makes the problem considerably easier.

Comment: @MaoWao Wait, what? That is not true! If $A$ is PSD, then $A$ is Hermitian which only implies that $C^T=-C$, but not $C=0$.

Comment: @Levent I see. You used a different (in my experience non-standard) notion of real and imaginary part. At least in operator algebras, it is common to call $(A+A^\ast)/2$ the real part and $(A-A^\ast)/2i$ the imaginary part of $A$. But I guess you used the entrywise real and imaginary part, right?

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, I used the entrywise real and imaginary part. I would call $(A+A^*)/2$ the Hermitian part and $(A-A^*)/2$ the skew Hermitian part of $A$, respectively. I didn't know that they were called the real and the imaginary part in different contexts. It does make sense though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will assume that $B^\top = B$ and $ C^\top =-C$ so that $A$ is hermitian. (Otherwise, I don't know what PSD means for a complex matrix.)

For the complex matrix $B+jC$, the quadratic form is

\begin{align}
Q(x,y)
&=(x+j y)^* (B+jC)(x+jy)\\
&=(x^\top -j y^\top)[(Bx-Cy)+j(By+Cx)]\\
&=x\cdot (Bx-Cy)+j x\cdot (By+Cx)-jy\cdot (Bx-Cy)+y\cdot(By+Cx)\\
&=(x\cdot Bx-x \cdot Cy+y\cdot By+y\cdot Cx)+j(x\cdot By+x\cdot Cx-y\cdot Bx+y\cdot Cy)
\end{align}
From here we may use the assumptions on $B,C$ to write
\begin{align}
x\cdot By&=By\cdot x=(By)^\top x=y^\top Bx=y\cdot Bx,\\
x\cdot Cx&=Cx\cdot x=(Cx)^\top x=-x^\top (Cx)=-x\cdot Cx=0,\\
y\cdot Cy&=Cy\cdot y=(Cy)^\top y=-y^\top (Cy)=-y\cdot Cy=0,\\
x\cdot Cy&=(Cy)\cdot x=(Cy)^\top x=- y^\top Cx=-y\cdot Cx
\end{align}
Hence the imaginary part of the quaratic form vanishes and the real part simplifies to $$Q(x,y)=x\cdot Bx+2(Cx)\cdot y+y\cdot By.$$ But this is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x^\top & y^\top \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B & C^\top \\ C & B\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$ That is, the quadratic form on $B+jC$ is equivalent to the quadratic form on $\begin{bmatrix} B & C^\top \\ C & B\end{bmatrix}$. Thus each is PSD if and only if the other is as well.