# Operator norm of a Hermitian operator

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following result mentioned in Sadri Hassani:-

[image: lemma]

The first inequality, i.e, $|\langle Hx|x\rangle| \le ||H||\ ||x||^2 = ||H||$ is straightforward from the definition of the norm of an operator. For the reverse inequality, the author mentioned the following procedure.

[image: operator_inequality]

I cannot figure out how they obtained the inequality using the above result. Also, I think that the result for $4\langle Hx|y\rangle $ should have a $-i$ instead of $i$ in the equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the choices given for $x$ and $y$, you have that $\langle Hx,y\rangle\in\mathbb R$, so the equality reduces to
$$
4\langle Hx,y\rangle=\big(\langle H(x+y),x+y)\rangle-\langle H(x-y),(x-y)\rangle\big).
$$
Also, $\|x\|=\|y\|=\|Hz\|^{1/2}\,\|z\|^{1/2}$. Then, using the parallelogram identity,
\begin{align}
4\|Hz\|^2&=4\langle Hx,y\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&\leq M\|x+y\|^2+M\|x-y\|^2\\[0.3cm] &=2M(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)\\[0.3cm]
&=4M\|Hz\|\,\|z\|. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am guessing that the part with iota in the equality for 4⟨Hx|y⟩  does not contribute to the real part as it is the expectation value of a hermitian operator which is always real. Also, I have always wondered how does one arrive at such methods of proving inequalities. Is it only practice and hit and trial or are there any set of rules that one should try to follow to get the result from scratch.