# How can we prove that Unitary Transformation is isometric?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, isometry

I am studying Image Processing in which unitary transforms play an important role, one reason that I found for their use in image transformation is isometry(they preserve distance), I found a relevant answer for this on the same site [The difference between an isometric operator and a unitary operator on a Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899230/what-is-the-difference-between-an-isometric-operator-and-a-unitary-operator-on-a). Where to prove the same author starts with, $$||Tx-Ty||=||x-y||$$this can be proven by $$|T|||x-y||$$ where $|T|=1$ and T is unitary, but here he further adds on to prove that

"Because of the definition of the norm in terms of the inner product and the definition of adjoint operators, this is equivalent to $$⟨T^HTx,x⟩=⟨x,x⟩\quad\quad \forall x$$ This implies that $T^H T=I$. Conversely, if $T^H T=I$, you can show that T is an isometry"

**Now this proof is necessary other wise any matrix with determinant 1 can be used for transformation, which off course isn't true**. Can somebody help me with the missing link, I am not an expert in linear algebra and just know basics of norm.

Comment: If you are familiar with the proof in real Euclidean spaces that orthogonal transformations preserve length (isometry), the proof for unitary transformations is very similar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what your question is. The answer at the link does not claim that $\|T(x-y)\| = \text{det}(T)\|x-y\|$ as you seem to be asserting. (In fact, this is surely false in general, as can be seen by taking any noninvertible $T$ where $x-y$ is not in the null space of $T$.)

Comment: That is what I want to say i am somewhere wrong in proving, because if that does happen then any matrix with 1 as a determinant can be used for image transformations which is not true.

Comment: Well, if your proof relies on the claim that $\|T(x-y)\| = \text{det}(T)\|x-y\|$, then this is wrong even if $\text{det}(T) = 1$. For example, take $T = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, $x = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and $y = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: $T^*T$ isn't referring to $T*T$ it means $T^H\times T$ or $T^* \times T$

Comment: I think I can prove it by $$(Ux-Uy)^{*T}(Ux-Uy)=(x-y)^{*T}(x-y)$$ if that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that if we have two vectors
$$ v =
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2 \\v_3
\end{pmatrix} \ \
 w =
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \\ w_2 \\w_3
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

we can rewrite the dot product $$\langle  v,  w\rangle = v^H \times w = \begin {pmatrix} v_1^* & v_2^* & v_3^*\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \\ w_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, we wish to show that the operators that preserve distances are exactly the unitary operators.

Let $T: V \to V$ be any operator.

Now, to show that $T$ preserves distances, we need that
$$
\langle T v, T w \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle
$$

this is because, if $T$ preserves the inner product structure, then it also preserves the metric generated by the inner product ($|v| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle})$

Now,

$$
\langle T v, T w \rangle = (T v)^H \times (T w) = (v^H T^H) (Tw) = v^H (T^HT) w
$$

However, we want
$$
\langle T v, T w \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle
$$

So this implies that,

$$
 v^H (T^HT) w = v^H w \\
\implies T^H T = I
$$

which tells us that any operator $T$ that preserves the inner product structure (and hence the metric) must be unitary.

Comment: $\langle v,w \rangle$ is defined as $v^H \times w$ not $v^T \times w$

Comment: is it same that  if I can prove $$||Ux-Uy||^2=||x-y||^2$$ then I can prove isometry

Comment: @PatrickAbraham - Apologies, I was assuming all reals. I'll change this

Comment: @PatrickAbraham - the solution is correct now I believe?

Comment: @Ankit - yes, I suppose it is, but how do you wish to prove that?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Since the original notation was for hermite, I would prefer to stick with it. PS.: Your proof was and is still more than just correct. It's a pleasure to read. Have a nice day!

Comment: @PatrickAbraham - cheers :)

Comment: By proving $$(Ux-Uy)^{*T}(Ux-Uy)=(x-y)^{*T}(x-y)$$ if that is correct

Comment: Yes I will take care of it, thanks!!

Comment: @Ankit replace both $v$, $w$ with $(x - y)$ in my proof and you get the proof of what you want. Notice that $Ux - Uy$ can we written as $U(x - y)$ by linearity. Then you can clearly see how they are equivalent. However, the proof I gave you is stronger, since it tells you that any hermite operator $H$ preserves __inner product__ as well, not just distance

Comment: @Ankit It is correct but it's $U^H$ not $U^T$. $U^T$ is only working for real entries! $$\overline{A}^T=A^H$$ $\quad A^*$ is, at least in my eyes, outdated and most of the time misleading.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Thanks !!