# A Finite Dimensional non-Unitary Isometry?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products, isometry

In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/900311) of a question [Difference between an isometric operator and a unitary operator on a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/899230/393259) states:

> On infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (**unlike in finite dimensional cases**), there are always nonunitary isometries.

So, I'm thinking that something must be wrong with the finite dimensional example that occurs to me? I'd appreciate feedback on this...

Consider a canonical injection of $T: R → R^2$ defined by $T(x) = (x, 0)$ with the usual Euclidean metrics. $T$ is linear, isometric, and not surjective.

Define $T^*: R^2 → R$ by $T^*(x, y) = x$. Then

1. $T^*$ is the (unique) adjoint of $T$: $〈 T(x), (x`, y`)〉 = x.x` = 〈 x, T^* (x`, y`)〉$
2. $T^*$ is the left inverse of $T$: $T^*( T(x)) = T^*(x, 0) = x,$ so $T^*( T(.)) = I.$

But for $y` ≠ 0$, $T( T^*(x`, y`)) = T(x`) = (x`, 0) ≠ (x`, y`)$, so $T( T^*(.)) \not = I,$ and therefore *T* is not unitary.

---

On reflection, I think the post cited refers specifically to **operators** on a single space rather than general linear transformations between different spaces. Can anyone confirm this is the cases and that my example is fine for an isometric transformation between different spaces ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I meant from a space to itself. An injective linear operator on a finite dimensional space (that is, to and from the same space) must be surjective.  Your example is a good one for a non-surjective isometry between different spaces.