# Isometric linear operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, isometry

Is it possible that an isometric (bounded) operator ${\rm T}: \mathcal H_1 \to \mathcal H_2$ with norm $\|\rm T\| = 1 $ is not unitary, i.e.  $\rm T^*T = I \neq TT^*$?

If yes, could you please provide some examples?

Comment: This question has a detailed answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899230/difference-between-an-isometric-operator-and-a-unitary-operator-on-a-hilbert-spa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The canonical example is the unilateral shift.

Take any separable Hilbert space $H$, and choose some orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for it. Then define
$$
S\sum_kc_ke_k=\sum_kc_ke_{k+1}. 
$$