# View the unitary group $U(n)$ as the group of linear isometries of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, hilbert-spaces, isometry

**The Statement**: Viewing $\mathbb{C}^n$ as an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space, we can view $U(n)$ as the group of linear isometries of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

(Definition: The **unitary group** $U(n)$ consists of all $A\in GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ with $AA^*=A^*A=I$, where $A^*=(\overline{A})^t$ is the adjoint matrix of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$.)

**Source**: *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Alexander S. Kechris.

**My Question**: I do not follow the statement at all, even after figuring out what Hilbert space and linear isometry are. Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899230/what-is-the-difference-between-isometric-and-unitary-operators-on-a-hilbert-spac