# How does $T$ being an isometry imply unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation on a complex inner product space $(V,\langle,\rangle)$ and suppose that $$\| T(v) \|=\| v \|$$ for all $v \in V$. Here the norm is the one induced by the inner product. How does this imply that $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for any $x,y \in V$?

Comment: You may look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57350/for-complex-matrices-if-langle-ax-x-rangle-langle-bx-x-rangle-for-all-x)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The Hermitian isometry condition $||T v|| = || v ||$ is equivalent to $\langle T v, T v \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$, and one can use the [Hermitian polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_complex_scalars) to write a Hermitian inner product $\langle a, b \rangle$ as a certain $\Bbb C$-linear combination of expressions of the form $\langle c, c \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

The key word is [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).