# Are unitary operators determined by their diagonal matrix coefficients?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex, infinite dimensional Hilbert space and let $A,B : H \rightarrow H$ be unitary operators such that $\langle A x , x \rangle = \langle B x ,x \rangle$ for all $x \in H$. Does it follow that $A = B$?

If $A$ is the identity operator, this is true since in that case,
$$
||x - Bx||^2 = ||x||^2 - 2 \Re{\langle Bx , x \rangle} + ||Bx||^2 = ||x||^2 - 2 \langle x,x \rangle + ||x||^2 = 0 
$$

However, I don't think that one can reduce to this case by considering $AB^{-1}$ or $B A^{-1}$.

My notes say that one should use the polarization identity

$$\langle x , y \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(||x + y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 + i ||x + i y||^2 - i ||x-i y||^2)$$
 but I don't see how.

Comment: Use `\|` instead of `||` to get proper double norm bars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assumption we have that
$$
  \langle (A - B)x ,x \rangle = 0
  \quad
  \text{for every $x \in H$}.
$$
It therefore sufficies to show that for any linear map $A \colon H \to H$ with
$$
  \langle A x, x \rangle = 0
  \quad
  \text{for all $x \in H$}
$$
we already have that $A = 0$.

---

Note that the linear map $A \colon H \to H$ results in a sesquilinear form $s \colon H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$ given by 
$$
  s(x,y) := \langle Ax, y \rangle
  \quad
  \text{for all $x, y \in H$}.
$$
This sesquilinear form is uniquely determined by its diagonal values, i.e. by the map
$$
  Q \colon H \to \mathbb{C},
  \quad
  x \mapsto s(x,x) = \langle Ax, x \rangle.
$$
This follows directly from the following polarization identity:
$$
    s(x,y)
  = \frac{Q(x+y) - Q(x-y) + iQ(x + iy) - iQ(x - iy)}{4}
$$
(Here we use that we are working over the complex numbers, where the polarization identity works for *all* sesquilinear forms.
This is different from the real case, where polarization only works for *symmetric* bilinear forms.)
If we have that $\langle Ax, x \rangle = 0$ for every $x \in H$, then $Q = 0$ and therefore $s = 0$.
Thus we have that
$$
  \langle Ax, y \rangle = 0
  \quad
  \text{for all $x, y \in H$}.
$$
By setting $y = Ax$ we find that $\|Ax\|^2 = 0$ for every $x \in H$, and therefore that $A = 0$.

---

Note that we do not need $A$, $B$ to be unitary.
We only require them to be linear.